# Safer way to realloc

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am implementing a function to safely realloc a structure in order not to lost the information if any allocation error occurs, something like this:

```
int foo (someStruct_t *ptr, int size)
{
    someStruct_t *tmp_ptr;

    tmp_ptr = realloc(ptr, size);

    if (tmp_ptr == NULL)
        return -1;

    ptr = tmp_ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

My doubt resides in the following: Am I not duplicating the allocated memory for the structure everytime I run this function? In my line of thought I should free one of the pointers before exiting, correct?

Comment: Where do you see the possibility for "*duplicating the allocated memory*"?

Comment: BTW. you are are aware that the new, the reallocated address is not passed to the caller of `foo()`, aren't you?

Comment: `ptr` is only local copy so the pointer that was passed to the function does not get updated.

Comment: What will your program do with the data if there is an allocation error then? Since this is most likely an indication of that the computer just ran out of memory and your program is about to get fried. How is it "safer" to pretend that nothing happened and continue running?

Comment: Sorry you are right, I just write this out of my head, in fact, in my program the someStruct_t *ptr is global. What gets duplicated is the memory allocated for the old ptr after the ptr=tmp_ptr, isn't my responsability to free it?

Comment: "in order not to lost the information if any allocation error occurs" -- no, you're doing nothing to achieve that , nor is it doable within the definition of the C standard, nor is it worth doing. Focus on learning the C language, which you have a poor grasp of, before attempting to save the world from allocation failures.

Comment: `ptr=tmp_ptr` is an assignment from a pointer to a pointer. It assigns the value of the from-pointer to the to-pointer. There is no allocation invoked here, as with every assignment.

Comment: ___Please do not change the question after you have got the answer, it makes the answer(s) invalid.___

Comment: "in fact, in my program the someStruct_t *ptr is global" -- which is a horrible thing to do. Your function achieves nothing that realloc alone doesn't, and its design is much worse.

Comment: "Am I not duplicating the allocated memory for the structure everytime I run this function?" -- No. Learn what a pointer is.

Comment: @lundin " How is it "safer" to pretend that nothing happened and continue running?" -- it's not clear he's doing that, since he returns -1 for allocation failure. His function merely wraps a much worse API around realloc; it doesn't achieve anything.

Comment: @JimBalter You are saying that this kind of aproach is pointless, because if I ran out of memory I am already in troubles, but it is not always quite like that.  My point is that by simply doing ptr = realloc(ptr, size); I will get a NULL pointer when no more memory can be allocated, despite I had valid data pointed by ptr.

Comment: So don't simply do that. All you need is `new_ptr = realloc(ptr, size); if (!new_ptr) { do_something_with(ptr); } else { ptr = new_ptr; }` ... much better than using a global. But the fact is that there's rarely anything useful to do with the old memory when you run out, and with the amount of available memory these days, if you run out then you probably have a bug. Writing bifurcated code that does one thing if you're out of memory and another if you're not is a waste of resources, complicates the code needlessly, and is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Code also incorrectly reports an error with `foo(ptr, 0)`.  A `NULL` return from `realloc(..., 0)` is not necessarily an error. Suggest `if (tmp_ptr == NULL)` --> `if (tmp_ptr == NULL && size != 0)`.

Comment: `realloc(ptr, size)` takes a size type of `size_t`, not `int`.  Better to use `int foo (someStruct_t *ptr, size_t size)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary and major problem here is, after a call to `foo()`, in the caller, the passed argument for `ptr` will not be changed, as it itself is passed by value.

You need to pass a pointer to the pointer which you want to be reallocated, in case you don't want to `return` the new pointer.

---

That said, there is no "duplication" of memory here.

- From `realloc()` point of view

  `realloc()`, if successful, returns the pointer to the new memory and handles the job of de-allocating the older one. You don't need to worry about any duplication or memory leaks.

  Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.5 (*emphasis mine*)

  > The `realloc` function **deallocates the old object pointed to by `ptr` and returns a
  >   pointer to a new object that has the size specified by `size`.** [....]
  >
  > [....] If memory for the new object cannot be
  >   allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged.
- From the assignment point of view

  A statement like `ptr = tmp_ptr;` does not duplicate the memory or memory contents the pointer points to, it is just having two copies of the same pointer. For example, You can pass either of them to `free()`.

So, bottom line, to answer the "question" in the question,

> *In my line of thought I should free one of the pointers before exiting, correct?*

No, you should not. You need to have the newly allocated pointer to be useful in the caller, `free()`-in it inside the called functions makes the whole function pointless. You should free the pointer from the caller, though.

Comment: Moreover, it may be released.

Answer (score 1):

```
int foo (someStruct_t **ptr, int size)
{
    someStruct_t *tmp_ptr;

    tmp_ptr = realloc(*ptr, size);

    if (tmp_ptr == NULL)
        return -1;

    *ptr = tmp_ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still, although this corrects the question's code, it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

the posted code contains several problems:

1. cannot change where a caller's pointer points without the address of that pointer, so use `**` in the parameter list and call the function using: `foo( &ptr, size);`
2. each reference to the callers' pointer must now be dereferenced via a `*`
3. usually the size refers to the number entries room to be allocated, so `size` needs to be multiplied by `sizeof( someStruct_t )`
4. note the use of `size_t` for the `size` parameter because `realloc()` is expecting the second parameter to have the type: `size_t`

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>   // realloc()

int foo (someStruct_t **ptr, size_t size)
{
    someStruct_t *tmp_ptr;

    tmp_ptr = realloc( *ptr, sizeof( someStruct_t) * size );

    if (tmp_ptr == NULL)
        return -1;

    *ptr = tmp_ptr;

    return 0;
} // end function: foo
```